# java write records to new line of file

Tags: java

every time the code runs i want the new record to be added to a new line

as it is when a new record is added it will write over previous line

```
private void writeFile() {
    String FILENAME = g.getText();
    String content = results;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(content.getBytes());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Saved", 0).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: What does this do: `openFileOutput`?

Comment: changed to MODE_APPEND but still cant get it to print record to new line how do i insert line feed

Comment: Most likely the problem is within that method. What I mean when I asked, was to ask you if it would be possible to post the content of that method.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write the "newline" character as well when writing data:

```java
private void writeFile() {
    String FILENAME = g.getText();
    String content = results;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(content.getBytes());
        fos.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But be careful with writing binary data like this. It's better to use e. g. `BufferedWriter` to write string data:

```java
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("filename"));
writer.write("Hello world!");
writer.newLine();
```

Comment: thank you i solved my problem by adding   fos.write("\n".getBytes());

Comment: It's not the best solution. I don't understand why did you put the newline character at the beginning of the line (in front of data) and also it's better to use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` instead of UNIX newline `"\n". Newline character is OS dependent.

Comment: the application is for android so only require Linux new line character and i put new line after the data also i tried System.getProperty("line.separator")  but it caused the application to crash

Comment: OK. On Anroid you could also call `System.lineSeparator()` http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator()